SVG, ширина фона не более ширины текста


<svg viewBox="0 0 250 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)" rx="5px"></rect>
<path d="M35.716 31.884a1.349 1.349 0 0 1-1.895.23L.517 6.011a1.35 1.35 0 1 1 1.667-2.125l33.252 26.05c.635.512.742 1.362.28 1.947z" fill="red"></path>
    <path d="M3.6 15.3v5.4c0 1.492 1.21 2.65 2.7 2.65h4.717l7.589 6.745c.335.349.763.506 1.196.506.25 0 .504-.052.74-.16.65-.29 1.06-.931 1.06-1.64v-2.832L4.993 12.954c-.827.461-1.392 1.283-1.392 2.346zm16.945-9.741a1.803 1.803 0 0 0-1.937.296l-6.519 5.794 9.513 7.46V7.198c0-.708-.41-1.4-1.057-1.64zm6.266 8.273a1.35 1.35 0 0 0-1.708 2.092c.634.523 1 1.277 1 2.076a2.68 2.68 0 0 1-1.002 2.075 1.35 1.35 0 0 0-.44 1.428l1.21.95c.029.001.055.018.084.018.3 0 .604-.1.854-.304A5.37 5.37 0 0 0 28.803 18c0-1.614-.726-3.128-1.992-4.168zm3.404-4.158a1.35 1.35 0 1 0-1.712 2.088c1.909 1.563 3 3.836 3 6.238 0 2.402-1.094 4.674-2.999 6.239-.059.048-.09.114-.138.17l2.126 1.666c2.355-2.067 3.711-4.987 3.711-8.075 0-3.212-1.451-6.25-3.988-8.326z"></path>

    <text x="41" y="23">test text</text>
</svg>



Как сделать, чтобы ширина красного фона была не более ширины текста. Текст может быть больше, может быть меньше

Чем вас  не устраивает обычный html, css и width: fit-content?

Шрифт не адаптируется относительно родительского блока. То есть размер шрифта статичен, какой бы размер блока не был...

Тут без js не обойтись

Так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637014/6339052

Сначала получаем ширину текста и потом присваиваем нужному ректу

https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OJebxGv - вот собственно демонстрация
